# How to change all row in a column of DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

This is an additional part inside project.

The idea is to create a new Form for users to search and edit cells value in datagridview from textbox without change to database.

When user is searching for a product number "111111" (one product has many IDs)

```
txtNum: 111111   ⧈ (btnEdit)
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|   ID   |     pNum     |
|   33   |    111111    |
|   2    |    111111    |
|   3    |    111111    |
|   4    |    111111    |  <-- s_DataGridView
|   5    |    111111    |
|   22   |    111111    |
|   1    |    111111    |
| *      |              |
 ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾
```

By using Filter method in BindingSource with connecting to the data from dataset table.

```
// Load data to dataset(DataTable)
this.s_Adapter.Fill(this.dataDataSet.tblData);
// Use Filter to get pNum
if (pNum == "") {
    s_BindingSource.Filter = "pNum IS NULL";
    s_BindingSource.AddNew();
}
else {
    txtNum.Text = pNum;
    s_BindingSource.Filter = "pNum = '" + pNum + "'";
}
```

It's working for a search.
Searching code (in KeyDown event to detect the Enter key pressed) to get all matches pNum and show them in s_DataGridView:

```
s_BindingSource.Filter = "pNum = '" + pNum + "'";
```

But editing, it does not work as expected.
Here is an editing code:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s_DataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++) {
        s_DataGridView[1, i].Value = txtNum.Text;
    }
}
```

And getting the result:

```
txtNum: 222222  <-- insert NEW pNum IN textbox and click on edit button --> ⧈ (btnEdit)
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|   ID   |     pNum     |
|   33   |    222222    |   <-- just the first row has been changed
|   3    |    111111    |
|   5    |    111111    |
|   22   |    111111    |
| *      |              |   <-- and some rows disappeared
 ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾
```

The target result:

```
txtNum: 222222   ⧈ (btnEdit)
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|   ID   |     pNum     |
|   33   |    222222    |
|   2    |    222222    |
|   3    |    222222    |
|   4    |    222222    |  <-- all rows changed after clicking on edit button
|   5    |    222222    |
|   22   |    222222    |
|   1    |    222222    |
| *      |              |
 ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾
```

So the question is:
1. Why a cells value changed only one row?
2. How to change them all from textbox without affecting the Database?

---

**Edited for an answer based on the suggestion in comment by jdweng:**

1. Because DataGridView is binding to DataTable.
2. DataGridView's cells values can't be changed directly while binding to outsource data, just change them in DataTable, it's all right, the Database will be safe. This will be re-coding in "Button Click Event". And since there are many methods to get access to DataTable, I would not dig into the details. Anyway, I used DataRow in the loop to get all done.

Comment: You are binding to a DataTable so change the values in the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks jdweng for the fast reply. Give me time to deal with it.

Comment: Bingo! The question is solved. Thank you again.